# How to make maven properties available to dropwizard yaml files

Tags: java, maven, swagger, dropwizard

I am using the swagger bundle to document my dropwizard resources. Following is the yaml file

```
swagger:
  resourcePackage: "com..resources"
  description: "<a href='http:/docsite/'>Workflow doc</a>"
  version: ${project.version}
```

I want to dynamically update the versin number from the POM file for which I gave maven resource filtering a try

```
<resources>
    <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/docker</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This does not evaluate the project version . I understand that the evaluation happens in the files that end up in the /target/classes of the project.

How can I use this maven property in my yaml file?

I also tried the follwing in my application classs

```
SwaggerBundleConfiguration swaggerConfig = configuration.getSwaggerBundleConfiguration();
    swaggerConfig.setVersion("${project.version}");
```

And changing the resource filtering to

```
<resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

But I dont see any changes on the UI

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution. In summary, populate a properties file with Maven properties using [Maven resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Then load those properties in your app and set them as system properties. Finally, configure Dropwizard to [substitute variables](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.0/docs/manual/core.html#environment-variables) in YAML with system properties.

Assuming the variable we are trying to substitute in the YAML is called `project.version`:

1. Create a properties file in `src/main/resources`. In this example I'll call it `maven.properties`.
2. In `maven.properties` add the property `project.version=${project.version}`
3. In the build section of your pom, add:

   ```
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
   ```
4. Create an implementation of `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor` that uses system properties as the lookup source:

```java
    package com.example.app;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrLookup;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor;

    /**
     * A custom {@link StrSubstitutor} using system properties as lookup source.
     */
     public class SystemPropertySubstitutor extends StrSubstitutor {
         public SystemPropertySubstitutor() {
             super(StrLookup.systemPropertiesLookup());
         }
     }
```

5. In your main Application class, add the following to `initialize`:

```java
    @Override
    public void initialize(final Bootstrap<AppConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("maven.properties"));
            System.setProperty("project.version", properties.getProperty("project.version"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        final StrSubstitutor substitutor = new SystemPropertySubstitutor();
        final ConfigurationSourceProvider configSourceProvider = new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(), substitutor);
        bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(configSourceProvider);
    }
```